# Mangle all variables except one with gulp-uglify

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

Is there a way to mangle all variables except a specific one with gulp-uglify?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There definitely is, I couldn't find any documentation for [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) regarding these sub-options, so relied on [grunt-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify) & wrote it the *gulp* way.

`.pipe( uglify({ mangle: {except: ['jQuery']} }) ) // for gulp-uglify ^2.0.1`

The above code will mangle every variable **except** `jQuery`

Hopefully this will still be useful for you. ;)

Sam.

========

**NB**: If you are using `gulp-uglify ^3.0.0` please replace `except` with `reserved` eg:

`.pipe( uglify({ mangle: {reserved: ['jQuery']} }) ) // for gulp-uglify ^3.0.0`

*Kudos to [Lukas Winkler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4398037/lukas-winkler)*

Comment: It seems like with UglifyJS 3 `except` was replaced with `reserved`. Otherwise it will throw `DefaultsError: `except` is not a supported option`

Answer (score 5):

That's right.

UglifyJS 3 `except` was replaced with `reserved`. Otherwise it will throw

`` DefaultsError: except` is not a supported option ``

it seem like this

`.pipe(uglify({mangle: {reserved: ['$.loadEditor']}}))`

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
.pipe(uglify({
  mangle: { toplevel: true, except: ['variable1', 'variable2',
  'function1'], 'function2' }
}))
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me what exactly toplevel does? And why function2 is written out of the array of except? I want to try this for my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
gulp.src(['src/*.js'])
    .pipe(uglify({
        mangle: {
            except: ['ExtensionId'] // (base on gulp-uglify v1.5.3)
        }
    }))
```

Comment: Thanks @sigma, I've updated the accepted answer now gulp-uglify has updated