# Prevent function name to get mangled while minification

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

I'm using gulp-uglify ~1.5.4 for my javascript minification, in a file a have this code : `columns[j].colDef.cellRenderer.name === 'dateRenderer'`, `cellRenderer` is a function so `cellRenderer.name` will return he name of that function.
So when the function is `dateRenderer()` that code should return `true` which doesn't happens since after the minification the function got mangled.

I found this thread : [Make gulp-uglify not mangle only one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694685/make-gulp-uglify-not-mangle-only-one-variable) but I don't want to tell uglify what variables to mangle and not, isn't there any other way to solve this ? like in AngularJS we are using the $inject service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to specify to uglifyjs what function names should it skip from mangling, **store that function's name as a string**.

```js
function dateRenderer() {
  // do something useful
}

dateRenderer.rendererName = 'dateRenderer'

// later ...
var fn = dateRenderer

if (fn.rendererName === 'dateRenderer') {
  console.log('ok!')
}
```

...or set its name after you called that specific function:

```js
function dateRenderer() {
  dateRenderer.rendererName = 'dateRenderer'
  
  // do something useful
}

// later ...
var fn = dateRenderer

// do something
dateRenderer()

if (fn.rendererName === 'dateRenderer') {
  console.log('ok!')
}
```